# Is there a package in R allowing to test whether a ROC curve is dominating the other?

Tags: r, classification, roc

Among other measures, I'd like to compare ROC curves for 2 classification methods. Is there a way to test automatically if one classifier performs better independent of the threshold? Is there a package which tests for domination?

Comment: Have you looked into the area under an ROC curve?

Comment: @ spdrnl Thanks for the question. Yes, I did. However, if the AUC is greater for let's say classifier 1, the ROC curve of classifier 2 could still dominate it for some thresholds, right?